# How to start a Maven Spring JSF 2.0 Richfaces project?

Tags: spring, jsf, maven, jsf-2, richfaces

For some of you it might sound trvial, but for days I have been fighting with `pom.xml` files and facets in order to build a Spring JSF 2.0 Maven project (run on tomcat 7.0) with RichFaces, but with no success. Can someone please reference me to a full working example ,I am using STS (tutorial from  scratch , I can download a fully working example but I want to learn how to create one  )  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after few days of work I came to the conclusion I have to do the dirty work therefore I will explain how I managed to start a project :

1. download sts
2. open template project , in my case it was spring integration with hibernate
3. right click on project-> preferences->facets
4. change to JSF 2.0 and web dynamic above 2.5(require above 1.5 java )
5. add to the maven dependencies (    pom.xml ):

   ```
     <!-- spring hibernate 3 -->

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
6. set up your

   ```
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   ```

the ref is pointed to this bean :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:."/>
<property name="username" value="sa"/>
<property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

or any other you decide ...

1. add to your project pom :

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
     <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.2.GA</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>           
       <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
       <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.2.GA</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   1. start praying it will work :)